# How do I create a post in Javascript to the .NetCore server

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-webapi

About Postman I can send data to the server and these are also received.
as Postman Json that is,

```
{
    "sender":"ingo@ingo.de",
    "message":"Postman"
}
```

When I execute my code in Javascript, it does not matter to the server.

```
 "use strict";
function handleSubmit() {
    let sendObject = new Object();
    sendObject.sender =  $('#EmailAddress').val();
    sendObject.message = $('#message').val();
    var data = JSON.stringify(sendObject);
    try {
       let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       let url = "https://myurl/api/home/externalEmail";
       xhr.open("POST", url, true);
       xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
       xhr.send(data);
     } catch(err) {
        alert('Error=' + err);
     }
}
```

When I display data in the alert, it looks like this,

```
{
   "sender":"ingo@ingo.de",
   "message":"Test Homepage"
}
```

At which point I am going to be wrong.

Comment: What error do you get back from the XMLHttpRequest or can you see in the network tab of any dev tools?

Comment: No data arrives on the server. If I send this over the JavaScript.

Comment: Have you checked by pressing `F12`? What is the error code in console tab? You could also check the network for this request.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[FromBody]` on your action parmeter

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromBody] MyModel model)
```

Comment: I do that too
[HttpPost("externalEmail")]
public async Task<IActionResult> EmailToSupport([FromBody] ExternalEmailViewModel email)

Answer (score 0):

I your requirement is not restricted to use jQuery then as you are already using it. Better use jQuery method to make API call as it will also take care of cross browser compatibility issues.

Here is an example..

```
// this is the id of the form
$("#idForm").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

    var form = $(this);
    var url = form.attr('action');

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
               alert(data); // show response from the php script.
           }
         });
});
```

BTW this is how AJAX call of jquery post call implementation looks like you may use it.

```
function postAjax(url, data, success) {
        var params = typeof data == 'string' ? data : Object.keys(data).map(
                function(k){ return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k]) }
            ).join('&');

        var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        xhr.open('POST', url);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState>3 && xhr.status==200) { success(xhr.responseText); }
        };
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.send(params);
        return xhr;
    }

    // example request
    postAjax('http://foo.bar/', 'p1=1&p2=Hello+World', function(data){ console.log(data); });

    // example request with data object
    postAjax('http://foo.bar/', { p1: 1, p2: 'Hello World' }, function(data){ console.log(data); });
```

Ping me in case of any query

Comment: At first thanks for your help. I am new with HTML / Javascript. I use your code:
var data = JSON.stringify(sendObject);
                const url = "https://myUrl/api/home/externalEmail";
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: data, // serializes the form's elements.
                success: function(data)
                {
                    alert(data); // show response from the php script.
                }
                });
But the server does not matter.

Comment: can u plz explain what error you are getting now. and how ur getting response on server

Comment: I do not get a message on the html page. In the server I use _logger.LogInformation. From the side nothing matters. From the postmaster I get data.

Comment: Just to be on same page check request body for data sent from client sides. From frontend inspect element and look for network tab there you can see what is going on with your API call. Check for status code after making api call and any other data that you see